# How does EFS use the user account to decrypt files?

Tags: windows, encryption, user-accounts, efs

My company uses pGina on its Windows machines so that we can log in using our LDAP accounts without Active Directory. Last week I accidentally entered my account password unmasked while SSH'd into one of our servers so I immediately changed it.

Later that day, I found that I could no longer open my EFS encrypted files on Windows. I recalled the password change so I went and changed my password back to what it was before and the files would open. I decrypted them and changed my password once again.

How is EFS functioning here? It must rely on the actual password being used to log-in and not the account itself. I realize this is a rare case and I doubt something like pGina was taken into account when it was designed.

Comment: "How is EFS functioning here?" - Security Certificate.  Related: [Accessing EFS-encrypted files after resetting Windows password](http://superuser.com/questions/767239/accessing-efs-encrypted-files-after-resetting-windows-password?rq=1)

Comment: Would be interesting to compare this with actual AD, which also allows such 'remote' password changes...